# Автоматически смонтировать сетевой диск

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Нужно при запуске сервера на ubuntu 16.04 автоматически смонтировать диск. Пытался реализовать через файл **/etc/fstab**, добавляя в него строки:

```
//192.168.1.1/'asusware.arm (at My_Passport)'   /mnt/WDPass/Download    cifs    user=***,password=***,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777   0       0
//192.168.1.1/'Video (at My_Passport)' /mnt/WDPass/Video cifs user=***,password=***,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

После запуска папки /mnt/WDPass/Video и /mnt/WDPass/Download пустые.

Если монтировать в ручную...

```
mount //192.168.1.1/'asusware.arm (at My_Passport)' /mnt/WDPass/Download -o username=***,password=***,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,iocharset=utf8
mount //192.168.1.1/'Video (at My_Passport)' /mnt/WDPass/Video -o username=***,password=***,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,iocharset=utf8
```

...то все работает.

```
mount -a
mount: /etc/fstab: ошибка разбора: игнорируется запись в строке 12.
mount: /etc/fstab: ошибка разбора: игнорируется запись в строке 13.
```

(12 и 13 как я понял это мои строки в fstab)

Пробовал менять пробелы на табы и обратно, убирать и ставить кавычки. Решение проблемы не нашел.

Comment: А в логах чё пишет? Если ошибка разбора, то прошерсти `/var/log`.

Comment: don Rumata, а какой файл в папке log мне нужен?

Comment: Чё-нить типа `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: `Mar  5 03:03:29 OPS-Server systemd[1]: Started Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling.
Mar  5 03:03:29 OPS-Server systemd[1]: Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
Mar  5 03:03:29 OPS-Server systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
Mar  5 03:03:29 OPS-Server systemd-remount-fs[443]: mount: /etc/fstab: ошибка разбора: игнорируется запись в строке 12.
Mar  5 03:03:29 OPS-Server systemd-remount-fs[443]: mount: /etc/fstab: ошибка разбора: игнорируется запись в строке 13.`

Comment: Вот первое упоминание данной строки в файле syslog.1

Comment: Я плохо разбираюсь в ubuntu и даже не знаю куда смотреть...

Comment: попробуйте убрать из экспортируемых имён спецсимволы — пробелы, кавычки, скобки.

Comment: Есть ли другие способы подхвата этих папок?

Comment: Что значит "устанавливает роутер"? Бубунта монтирует разделы согласно их названиям, которые лейблы. Поменяй их - поменяются точки монтирования. Сделать можно через `gparted`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый день! а попробуйте вместо пробелов - \040, т.е. что то в духе

```
//192.168.1.1/asusware.arm\040(at\040My_Passport) /mnt/WDPass/Download cifs user=***,password=***,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode‌​=0777 0 0
//192.168.1.1/Video\040(at\040My_Passport) /mnt/WDPass/Video cifs user=***,password=***,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode‌​=0777 0 0
```